# Why JUnit Plugin on Jenkins doesn't provide report?

Tags: jenkins, junit, pytest

I’m really stuck on generating a report from my pytest runs.

This the pipeline script (linked to Github):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/main']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/raul-parada/Python-Selenium.git']])
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/raul-parada/Python-Selenium.git'
                sh 'python3 test_*.py'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'python3 -m pytest'
            }
        
        }
        
        stage('Publish junit report') {
            steps {
                junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: 'result.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true, skipMarkingBuildUnstable: true
            }
        
        }
        stage('reports') 
        {
            steps {
                script {
                    allure([
                        includeProperties: false,
                        jdk: '',
                        properties: [],
                        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                        results: [[path: '**/target/allure-results']]
                        ])
                        }
                    }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have installed JUnit, HTML Publishing, Allure, however, I do not how to get a report by JUnit neither Allure. Please, could you guide me? Thanks in advance.